# Input, sys.stdin and functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, calculation

I created a function that takes 3 arguments:
(n,m,H are integers)

```
def Day(n,m,H):
    ...
```

However, I have to use:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line ,end = " ")
```

I tried a function that only requires one argument and did this, which worked.

(x is an integer)

```
def Square(x):
    y = x*x
    return y 

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = int(line)
    print(Square(line),end = " ")
```

I'm unsure as to how to do use it when there are 3 arguments. How would I do this?

Comment: This makes little sense, it is almost as if you are asking 3 separate questions... Please read [ask]

Comment: Maybe wait for 3 loops? Maybe type each value with a comma?

Comment: Anyway, as a start, why are you using `sys.stdin` and not `input()`?

Comment: The question I'm asking is how would I format 'for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line ,end = " ")' when I have 3 arguments instead of 1. I know how to do it for 1 but not when there are 3 arguments.

Comment: 3 arguments for what? `print`? `Day`? Please edit the question itself with details rather than in the comments

Comment: 3 arguments for the function Day. Mureinik has solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `split` the line you get from `stdin`:

```py
for line in sys.stdin:
    d = Day(*line.split())
```